# Make a MySQL database always start auto_increment at 1000

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Using MySQL or PHP (in Laravel 5.3), is it possible to automatically set `auto_increment` to 1000 anytime a new table is created?

To be clear, I know I can call `ALTER TABLE member AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;` to do this after creating a table and that I can incorporate in the code to create the table. Im looking for a way to have this happen automatically.

To elaborate, I use laravel and in my database migrations I currently do this:

```
  Schema::create('member', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        // ... 
  });
  DB::update("ALTER TABLE member AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;");
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to script it somehow through MySQL or PHP so that something equivalent to `DB::update("ALTER TABLE member AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;");` anytime I create a table

Comment: No. I read the manual at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html and https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp . There are no way to do that except alter in mysql

Comment: @sukalogika Maybe not with MySQL directly since there is no `ON CREATE TABLE` trigger, but there certainly should be a way to script this into Laravel, Im gonna look into extending the `Schema` class.

Comment: Would you be okay with having a line inside your create statement, something like `$table->options('AUTO_INCREMENT', 1000);`, or do you want your application just hardcoded to always set the auto inc to 1000? (Note, that code does not exist, just pseudo-code to help the question)

Comment: @patricus If possible, id like my application or database hardcoded to always set the auto inc to 1000. Im looking at extending the `Blueprint` and `Builder` classes now

Comment: Gotcha. I have a package that customizes Laravel migrations ([shiftonelabs/laravel-nomad](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-nomad)), so I was just gauging if it would be useful to you if I added this type of functionality to the package. However, the automated feature you're looking for seems very application specific and would not be good for a generic package.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in the docs of MySQL - you can add the AUTO_INCREMENT option while creating the table: [MySQL CREATE Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

Comment: As you can see in my question, that's not what I'm asking

Comment: @delighted Ok, in that case: Yes, technically it is possible to add such kind of functionality. The easiest way would be to create a function, that calls Schema::create, passes the arguments to it and after calls DB:update with the ALTER TABLE

e.g. `function easy($params, $params2, ...) {
    Schema::create('member', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        // ... 
  });
  DB::update("ALTER TABLE member AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;");
}`

then just call the function to create your tables

Comment: That's a fair stab at it. I'm looking for something a bit more elegant though. I'm testing extending the blueprint now. Looks promising